# Trying to get bi-monthly weekday recurrence using the Montrose gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails app with an alert that goes out to users bi-monthly but only on weekdays.
For example:
July 2020 - The 1st is a Wednesday and the 16th is a Thursday so the alerts should go out the 1st and 16th.
August 2020 - The 1st is a Saturday and the 16th is a Sunday so the alerts should go out on Monday the 3rd and Monday the 17th.

As far as I can tell the Montrose gem only supports recurrence on specific week days or dates. Is there a way to specify what I have described?